# VueJs 2 fetching data from json to make navigation

Tags: vuejs2

I have fetched the following json into my navigation for loop.
This works, but when i paste `{{item.navitems.navitem.name}}` into to="" i am getting this error.

How can i achieve this working?

Error:

[image]

Loop:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li v-for="item in items">
        <router-link to="" tag="li" active-class="active"><a>{{item.navitems.navitem.name}}</a></router-link>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Json:

```
[
  {
    "navitems": {
      "navitem": {
        "name": "Home",
        "url": ""
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "navitems": {
      "navitem": {
        "name": "About",
        "url": "/about"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you need a null check, like following:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li v-for="item in items">
        <router-link v-if="item.navitems && item.navitems.navitem" :to="item.navitems.navitem.name" tag="li" active-class="active">
             <a>{{item.navitems.navitem.name}}</a>
        </router-link>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Edit**: as par suggestion, making it more concise:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <router-link v-for="item in items" v-if="item.navitems && item.navitems.navitem" :to="item.navitems.navitem.url" tag="li" active-class="active" exact>
        <a>{{item.navitems.navitem.name}}</a>
    </router-link> 
</ul>
```

Comment: please remove the first li and put the v-for into the router-link and add exact. <router-link  v-for="item in items" v-if="item.navitems && item.navitems.navitem" :to="item.navitems.navitem.url" tag="li" active-class="active" exact><a>{{item.navitems.navitem.name}}</a></router-link>

Comment: @Bas Thanks for making it better :)